# How to remove this white space?

Tags: php, regex

I have this code-

```
<?php
$json = 'Two large sardines are seasoned and grilled, then served in a light wine sauce with chopped tomato and generous drizzle of olive oil.  Fresh and delicious.';
print_r(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$json));
?>
```

How can i remove these white space b4 `Fresh` .
Please help,
thanks

Comment: But  your code does remove them. Or do you want to remove both spaces?

Comment: What isn't working with your current code?

Comment: Is what you have at the moment not working? What do you get and what do you expect instead?

Comment: Just a guess. Do you assign new values after replace to the `$json`? I like such questions. The are like quests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo str_replace('  ', ' ',$json);
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
str_replace('  ', ' ', $yourString)
```

keep in mind it will remove all double spaces too

Answer (score 2):

To replace all multiple spaces, try this:

```
preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}/', ' ', $json);
```

Edit for explanation: `{2,}` means two or more of the preceeding character class, in this case a space).

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
preg_replace('/[ ]+/', ' ', $json);
```

Comment: @dfsq ...only not as good, because it only matches one type of whitespace character.

Comment: Uh yes, you are right. I didn't see it cause I usually use chars classes inside `[]`. So, OP code already works, in fact...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, does it not?

Also. this:

```
<?php
$json = 'Two large sardines are seasoned and grilled, then served in a light wine sauce with chopped tomato and generous drizzle of olive oil.  Fresh and delicious.';
print_r(str_replace("  "," ", $json));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo str_replace('  ', '',$json);
```